# Wine systray not working on Unity Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, wine, system-tray

The problem is that the wine systray is not working in my Unity desktop on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any other app for Ubuntu (Skype, Steam-ubuntu version, Transmission) works fine, just the Wine systray is not appearing.

I reset Unity, reinstalled it, reinstalled wine and I can't make it work.

Comment: I had this problem when installed dotnet45 with winetricks: the dotnet3 installer minimized itself to the tray during the installation and I couldn't get the dialog back. The solution: `winetricks -q --unattended dotnet45`

Answer (score 1):

Wine (Windows) System Tray does not work in Ubuntu. There are two options:

**1. Emulate a virtual desktop**

Use `POL -> Configure -> [select app] -> Wine -> Configure Wine -> Graphics -> Emulate a virtual desktop` to run the application from the virtual desktop. When you run the application this way, it runs in a small windows screen with a System Tray. Once the application is minimised to the System Tray, you can left-click it. I couldn't get right-click to work.

**2. Indicator Systemtray Unity App**

The [Indicator Systemtray Unity app](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity) by GGleb adds the Wine (Windows) System Tray into the Unity Application Indicator.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity
```

You may need to reboot to get the System Tray to show up. As before, left-click worked for me but right-click did not.