# Show Wine (Windows) System Tray in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, wine, indicator, system-tray

I cannot figure out how to see and access Wine apps minimised to the windows system tray. Any ideas?

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a windows application running on Wine and installed through PlayOnLinux. That application minimises to the windows system tray. However, once minimised, that application is not shown on the Launcher or in the Unity Application Indicator (I believe that's the correct name for the system-tray that sits on the top right corner). The application is still shown on System Monitor so I know it's still running.

Comment: Related [Wine application in system tray](http://askubuntu.com/q/666439) and [Wine Systray Not working on Unity Ubutnu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/517825), unfortunately there's no answer for either if those questions.

Comment: @JonasCz, there were a few threads about installing the Unity Systray  and white-listing and  but I couldn't figure out whether that was a terminology issue (ie Application Indicator being referred to as the Systray) or whether there was actually a separate Unity Systray.

Comment: Try `configure wine`-> `Graphics`-> `Emulate a virtual desktop` and see if you can un-minimize the application from the virtual desktop.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Thanks,  that helped - I can now see the minimised application in the virtual desktop system tray and can maximise it. Unfortunately it looks like there is reduced functionality with the virtual desktop. The only way to close the application is to right click in the system tray -> exit but this cannot be done in the virtual desktop.

Comment: You can use playonlinux and create a separate virtual drive for the program you want. Then if you press `configure` at `Wine` tab there is a `Kill processes` button. There is also the script at `Tools`-> `Close all PlayOnLinux software`. I can't think of any other workaround.

Comment: Closing the application is not a problem - I can just close the virtual desktop or just kill using System Monitor. Either way, I get the message
Error in POL_Wine - Wine seems to have crashed
Your original solution work of using virtual desktop seems to be the best workaround so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicator extension organizes system tray icons into a drop down, which solves this problem for me with Wine apps.  Thanks to Gleb Golovachev

https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity

Comment: That did add the windows system tray into a drop down in the Unity Application Indicator. Unfortunately the right click does not work, but I haven't found a better option than this app.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. I can see the indicator but nothing is shown there. I know both of my windows programs are running without a problem, but given that they only work from the systray and when started they don't have a window (they go directly to systray) I have no way to access them at all

Comment: Worked for me. Even the right-click works fine. I see my wine tray app in the indicator menu in my unity top bar and can use left and right clicks on it \o/